# Grenade spawns in the wrong location

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In my game I want to have a floating monster that's attack throws a grenade at the player. My problem is that the grenade only spawns in `0, 0, 0`. In my script I make it so that the zombies spawns in on its own location but for some reason that doesn't work. I tried making it spawn by having the spawn location equal `new Vector3(100, 100, 100)` but it still spawned at `0, 0, 0`. I know that the co-routine runs because I put a `Debug.Log`. Thanks for the help!

Edit #2: I can't have a rigidbody on the script. I have edited the movement script and I have found that no mater what if a rigidbody is added then it will go to `0, 0, 0`.

Edit #3: I updated the scripts

Here is my script: (Sorry if the code is bad)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ZKAttack_lvl3 : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform Player;
    public float MoveSpeed = 2.0f;
    public float InRadius = 10.0f;
    public float AttackRange = 15.0f;

    private Coroutine hasCourutineRunYet;

    public GameObject grenade;
    public GameObject FloatingMonster;
    private Vector3 FloatingMon;
    private Animator anim;
    private Rigidbody rigid;

    private void Start()
    {
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
        Player = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Player")[0].transform;
        rigid = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        
    }

    void Update()
    {
        Player = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Player")[0].transform;
        transform.LookAt(Player);

        float dstSqr = (Player.position - transform.position).sqrMagnitude;
        bool inRadius = (dstSqr <= InRadius * InRadius);
        bool inAttackRange = (dstSqr <= AttackRange * AttackRange);        
        anim.SetBool("AttackingPlayer", inAttackRange);
        if (inRadius)
        {
            transform.position += transform.forward * MoveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        }

        rigid.AddForce(1, 10, 1);

        if (inAttackRange)
        {
            if (hasCourutineRunYet == null)
            {
                hasCourutineRunYet = StartCoroutine(GrenadeAttack());
            }
        }

        
    }

    IEnumerator GrenadeAttack()
    {        
        FloatingMon = FloatingMonster.transform.position;        
        GameObject bulletObject = Instantiate(grenade, FloatingMonster.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);       

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(2.0f);
    }
}
```

Edit: This is the code for the movement:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GrenadeMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 10f;

    public float lifeDuration = 4.0f;

    private float lifeTimer;

    private Coroutine hasCourutineRunYet;
    
    private Transform Player;

    public SphereCollider sphereCollider;
    

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        lifeTimer = lifeDuration;

        sphereCollider.enabled = false;     

        Player = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Player")[0].transform;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {   
        lifeTimer -= Time.deltaTime;

        if (lifeTimer >= 3f)
        {
            Player = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Player")[0].transform;
            transform.LookAt(Player);

            transform.position += transform.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime;
        }

        if (lifeTimer >= 0f)
        {
            transform.position = speed * transform.up * Time.deltaTime;         
            transform.position = speed * transform.forward * Time.deltaTime;            
        }


        if (lifeTimer <= 0f)
        {
            if (hasCourutineRunYet == null)
            {
                hasCourutineRunYet = StartCoroutine(GrenadeExplosion());
            }

        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider coll)
    {
        if (coll.gameObject.tag == "Player")
        {
            if (hasCourutineRunYet == null)
            {
                hasCourutineRunYet = StartCoroutine(GrenadeExplosion());
            }
        }


    }

    IEnumerator GrenadeExplosion()
    {
        sphereCollider.enabled = true;

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1.0f);
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

Comment: Also I forgot to put this but I know the `FloatingMonster` is attached to the script so it isn't because I forgot to attach it.

Comment: Do any scripts other than this one access the grenade’s position? What components are on the grenade?

Comment: @ken It has a rigid body, box collider, sphere collider. It has a script one it for movement but that shouldn't have anything to do with its spawn location

Comment: Try removing the Rigidbody and see if that fixes it. (Just for the time; for debugging)

Comment: @ken it works now. I guess it interfered with it somehow

Comment: I’ll try to find a way to fix it, with the Rigidbody.

Comment: The movement script might have something to do with the spawn location if the movement changes the location in the first frame of its existence. It might be worthwhile to add that as well. As well, instead of accessing the position of a spawned object, [`Instantiate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html) has overloads allowing you to specify where an object should spawn. `Instantiate(grenade, FloatingMonster.transform.position, Quaternion.Identity);`. I do not think this will solve your issue, so please post the other code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help of @ken I figured out that I couldn't use a rigidbody so I changed the insantiation to this: `GameObject bulletObject = Instantiate(grenade, FloatingMonster.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);`. I then changed the movement script for it to:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GrenadeMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 10f;

    public float lifeDuration = 4.0f;

    private float lifeTimer;

    private Coroutine hasCourutineRunYet;
    
    private Transform Player;

    public SphereCollider sphereCollider;

    public Vector3 velocity;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        lifeTimer = lifeDuration;

        sphereCollider.enabled = false;     

        Player = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Player")[0].transform;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {   
        lifeTimer -= Time.deltaTime;

        if (lifeTimer >= 2f)
        {
            Player = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Player")[0].transform;
            transform.LookAt(Player);

            transform.position += transform.forward * 5 * Time.deltaTime;
        }

        if (lifeTimer >= 0f && lifeTimer <= 2f)
        {           
            transform.position = 9.18f * transform.up * Time.deltaTime;         
            transform.position = 9.18f * transform.forward * Time.deltaTime;            
        }


        if (lifeTimer <= 0f)
        {
            if (hasCourutineRunYet == null)
            {
                hasCourutineRunYet = StartCoroutine(GrenadeExplosion());
            }

        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider coll)
    {
        if (coll.gameObject.tag == "Player" || coll.gameObject.tag == "Terrain")
        {
            if (hasCourutineRunYet == null)
            {
                hasCourutineRunYet = StartCoroutine(GrenadeExplosion());
            }
        }


    }

    IEnumerator GrenadeExplosion()
    {
        sphereCollider.enabled = true;

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1.0f);
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

Thank you for all your help, I have been trying to fix this all week.

Answer (score 1):

You could set its position in the Instantiate line. Instantiate has several arguments. You can set its position in Instantiate, as well as its rotation and parent.

Set it to this:

```cs
    IEnumerator GrenadeAttack()
    {        
        GameObject bulletObject = Instantiate(grenade, FloatingMonster.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(2.0f);
    }
```

Comment: I got the error: `error CS0117: 'Quaternion' does not contain a definition for 'Identity'`. What should I do?

Comment: @AryaAkhavein lowercase i in identity. Use `Quaternion.identity` not `Quaternion.Identity`.

Comment: should I have a rigidbody on the grtenade?

Comment: I tried it with the rigidbody but it didn't work. It spawns in the right place though if I don't have the rigidbody

Comment: @AryaAkhavein Did you copy and paste my code and replace it with your previous coroutine?

Comment: Yes, I did add it

Comment: @AryaAkhavein I am on a mobile device right now, and will be able to test this in an hour or so.